# Nginx error with configuration wile reverse proxy shows "Welcome to nginx" when starting nginx

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, nginx

This is my first time playing around with nginx. I have 2 express servers running in my localhost in port 3001 and 3002. Which is running perfectly.
I am using ubuntu these are following steps I have taken for nginx.

- First I used sudo apt-get install nginx
- delete default file in sites-enabled and sites-available **sudo rm
  -f default**
- create default file in sites-available where I have these codes (just trying to run  one server in port 3001 for now.) **sudo vi default**
  server
     {
   listen 80;
   location  / 
       {
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.100.5:3001";
        }
    }
- symlink default from sites-available to sites-enabled : 
  **sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**
- start nginx  **sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start**

All I get is Welcome to nginx If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

- also I tried using this configuration in sites-enabled

  **upstream project {
      server http://localhost:3001;
      }
  server {
      listen 80;
      }
  }**

but it yield to same result. Please any guidance will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to to use [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) with the local host and without quotes.

Say you want the application on port `3001` as your website, you need to configure it like that:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

This code needs to be in the `server` block of your `default` file.

It will pass all traffic from the location `/` (your web root) to the port `3001`.

A complete example would look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

> proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;

This will pass all traffic to the `port 3001`.

---

> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

This will pass informations such as the IP which made the call to the proxied server.

---

> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

This will forward the used sheme/protocol information of the request.

Comment: will give it a try can you please tell me whats this does  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

Answer (score 1):

Mostly your configuration file problem.
see, below example different express apps running in 3000 and 3001 ports. this is how the config file looks like in my nginx config file

```
server {  
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name stage.chat.in www.stage.chat.in;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
server {  
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name api.chat.in www.api.chat.in;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3002;
    }
}
```